# How to import actual data rather than formatted data from google sheets?

Tags: import, webservices, spreadsheets

I have data in my google sheets which is extracted using:

```
httpRequest=HTTPRequest[<|
    "Scheme"->"https",
    "User"->None,
    "Domain"->"docs.google.com",
    "Port"->None,
    "Path"->{"","spreadsheets","d","...","gviz","tq"},
    "Query"->{"tqx"->"out:html","tq"->"","gid"->"..."},
    "Fragment"->None
|>]

httpResponse=URLRead[httpRequest]

data=Import[httpResponse,"FullData"][[2]]
```

But is coming out as follows:

> { {"Date:","3/6","Time In:","11:00","Time Out:","12:30"},
> {"Date:","3/13","Time In:","11:00","Time Out:","12:30"},
> {"Date:","3/20","Time In:","11:00","Time Out:","12:30"}, ... }

While the actual data is:

> { {"Date:","3/6/2021","Time In:","11:00:00 AM","Time Out:","12:30:00 PM"},
> {"Date:","3/13/2021","Time In:","11:00:00 AM","Time Out:","12:30:00 PM"},
> {"Date:","3/20/2021","Time In:","11:00:00 AM","Time Out:","12:30:00 PM"}, ... }

My issue is the data coming out from the request is the formatted data rather than the actual data from the cell. How do get the underlying data actually stored in the cells so I can recognize it as Mathematica date and time objects?

Comment: It's possible that there's a better way to do it than `Import[httpResponse,"FullData"]`, but I cannot reproduce the `URLRead`.

Comment: I don't know how you publish your data, but on my personal account using `Publish to the web`, publishing data similar to yours with date formats in `XLSX` and `CSV` formats, I could receive the whole data. my code : `a=URLRead@HTTPRequest[URL]; ImportString[a["Body"], "XLSX"]`. Using `XLSX` will give `DateObject` but with `CSV` you should parse a string.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual document that you are trying to import?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `httpResponse = URLRead[httpRequest]`returns: "Not Found". Therefore I take the test data from your question.

You can fix the wrong format by the following:

```
d = {{"Date:", "3/6", "Time In:", "11:00", "Time Out:", 
    "12:30"}, {"Date:", "3/13", "Time In:", "11:00", "Time Out:", 
    "12:30"}, {"Date:", "3/20", "Time In:", "11:00", "Time Out:", 
    "12:30"}};
d = (tmp = #; tmp[[2]] = tmp[[2]] <> "/2021"; tmp) & /@ d;
d = (tmp = #; tmp[[4]] = tmp[[4]] <> ":00 AM"; tmp) & /@ d;
d = (tmp = #; tmp[[6]] = tmp[[6]] <> ":00 PM"; tmp) & /@ d;
d

{{"Date:", "3/6/2021", "Time In:", "11:00:00 AM", "Time Out:", 
  "12:30:00 PM"}, {"Date:", "3/13/2021", "Time In:", "11:00:00 AM", 
  "Time Out:", "12:30:00 PM"}, {"Date:", "3/20/2021", "Time In:", 
  "11:00:00 AM", "Time Out:", "12:30:00 PM"}}
```